# the ABI of passing union with long double has changed in GCC 4.4

Tags: c

I have an union with a long double field.

I initialize a field and pass it to a function.

```
my_union foo;
foo.long_double = 10.10;
bar = baz(foo);
```

When compiling this code I get:

```
the ABI of passing union with long double has changed in GCC 4.4
```

Seem to be related to the changes mentioned here: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html

Does this mean I cannot pass an union having a long double as field? Why is this? And how can I solve this since I wanna use long double for storing large values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What this means is the resulting code is not binary compatible with code compiled with previous versions of GCC, so if you're passing it between libraries between binaries compiled with the current version and a previous version, it's not going to work. (see comments for info about memory layout for network transport and saving to files)

As you can see from the link you provided:

`Code built with previous versions of GCC that uses any of these is not compatible with code built with GCC 4.4.0 or later.`

Either don't do it, or make sure all your code that uses unions mentioned in the changelog are compiled on the same compiler version (or technically ABI).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

Comment: One clarification: the docs say that the ABI for passing these  unions as parameters has changed, not their memory layout (probably the registers involved). So moving them over the networks or saving them in files should be safe.

Comment: I changed the field to double and it works now. But why the design decision that long double is forbidden?

Comment: So why the decision that it's okay to pass an union with double fields, but not long double fields?

Comment: it IS ok.  It's just not ok to do it across libraries compiled with different versions.

Comment: Like.. they just had to change something that wasn't backwards compatible.  You can still do it, there was never anything wrong with doing it, they just made a change and you can't use the old version and the new version together.  Just recompile any old code (this probably doesn't even affect you) that you would have lying around with the old compiler using this union and you're golden.

Comment: But the only libraries I am using are the standard libraries provided by the same gcc. What is the reason for this not working?

Comment: You've never said anything isn't working.  I can't easily reproduce this, but this is most likely a compiler warning that you can ignore if you understand what it's warning you about and it doesn't affect you.  It will most likely be removed in a subsequent version of GCC.  If something isn't working, you'll need to specify exactly what isn't working, what it's doing wrong, and what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use options -msse2 or -march=k8 while compilling

Comment: From the description the gcc changelog, it is likely the new version is probably the right way to do it, so you should try to make it work how it is now before looking for workarounds that may not even be necessary.  But if you need it, this may be worth looking at - I don't know.